# I can not get data from firebase from a specific user (using the uid check method)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I ordered that when a user adds information, he also transfers his uid from another user with it; when receiving a uid, the received uid is compared with the uid from the folder with users.  If they match, the data of a certain user (number, name) is received.  User Model

```
public class ShopUser {
    private String client_shop,numberphone_shop,ShopInfouid;
    public ShopUser(){
    }
    public ShopUser(String client_shop, String numberphone_shop, String shopInfouid) {
        this.client_shop = client_shop;
        this.numberphone_shop = numberphone_shop;
    this.ShopInfouid=shopInfouid;
    }
    public String getClient_shop() {
        return client_shop;
    }
    public void setClient_shop(String client_shop) {
        this.client_shop = client_shop;
    }
    public String getNumberphone_shop() {
        return numberphone_shop;
    }
    public void setNumberphone_shop(String numberphone_shop) {
        this.numberphone_shop = numberphone_shop;
    }
    public String getShopInfouid() {
        return ShopInfouid;
    }
    public void setShopInfouid(String shopInfouid) {
        ShopInfouid = shopInfouid;
    }
}
```

validation method

```
ShopInfoRef.orderByChild("ShopInfouid").equalTo(getIntent().getExtras().get("UidShop").toString())
////UidSop это принятый uid переносится из другого активити  а ShopInfouid это uid пользователя так называется в бд////
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
phone=snapshot.getValue(ShopUser.class).getNumberphone_shop();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(OplataActivity.this, "Данных нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
```

initialization

```
private String phone;
    ShopInfoRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("shop");
```

tried to check in the log d but gave an error that the phone string has a null value and tried to pass this string to the phone open method, but the required number does not appear there, here is the method

```
image_phone_shop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent ohoneIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                ohoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ phone));
                startActivity(ohoneIntent);
            }
        });
```

Here is the users folder in which the uids of users from it are compared with the accepted uid
[image: user]

Here is the data folder where the uid is taken from for comparison
[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to handle this list by looping over `snapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot shopUserSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        phone=shopUserSnapshot.getValue(ShopUser.class).getNumberphone_shop();
    }
}
```

Also: please never leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring potential errors. At its very least it should look like:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException()l
}
```